# Time with chars conversion

Tags: r, time, time-format

I have this vector

```
time = c("2m 14,8s", "1h 47m 46,9s", "34,7s")
```

And I would like to get this (convert time to secs)

```
time = c(134.8, 6466.9, 34.7)
```

I try lapply that split my string and find character that indicates hours or minutes

```
lapply(str_split(sub(",", ".", time), " "), function(x) 
  ifelse(grepl("h", x), sub("[a-z]", "", x) * 120, 
  ifelse(grepl("m", x), sub("[a-z]", "", x) * 60, NULL)))
```

but this error occurs

```
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

and my second problem is that I don't know how to sum output

Comment: `"1h 47m 46,9s"` should be 6466.9 sec

Comment: Yes, works very well, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `','` with `'.'` and convert the abbreviations of hours, minutes, and seconds to upper-case characters so that `as.duration()` from `lubridate` can recognize and change them to a duration.

```r
library(lubridate)

as.numeric(as.duration(toupper(sub(',', '.', time))), "seconds")

# [1]  134.8 6466.9   34.7
```